Unable to send or receive proper strings through UART avr-c
I'm trying to program an ATMEGA2560-16AU based board that I've developed in AVR-C and I wanted to create a few functions to communicate via serial UART. So far, I've successfully managed to send and read single characters, and I've even made some code to test this using an led on port F0. But I need to be able to read and send character arrays over UART and thus far I've only seemingly been able to read strings that I send to the MCU and echo these back. But when I try to compare the received strings with other strings nothing works, as though it receives garbage. I then wrote a function to send strings back the strings that it reads and they seem just fine, exactly as I write them. But then I tried sending some other character array (ptr[]) and this one seems to print garbage! However, it only prints garbage if the character array holds more than 3 characters, cause if I try to print "hei" or "bye" it works fine. I can't find any explanation for this, so any help is welcomed.
This is the code from my main.c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "config.h"
#include "uart.h"

int main(void)
{
    USART0_init();

    DDRF |= (1 << PF0);
    char read[100];
    char ptr[100]="he\n";
    sei();

    while (1) 
    {
        //unsigned char received_char = USART0_receive();
        //USART0_send(received_char);
        //if(received_char=='s') PORTF &= ~(1 << PF0);
        //else if (received_char=='h') PORTF |= (1 << PF0);

        USART0_read_string(read, sizeof(read));
        if(strcmp(read, "ST") == 0) PORTF |= (1 << PF0);
        else if(strcmp(read, "SO") == 0) PORTF &= ~(1 << PF0);
        USART0_send_string(read);
        //USART0_send_string("RECEIVED\n");
        _delay_ms(10);
    }
}

And this is my uart.c
#include "uart.h"

void USART0_init(void){
    //USART BAUD RATE SETUP
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char) (BRC >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char) BRC;
    
    //RX TX ENABLE
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0)  | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void USART0_send(unsigned char data) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

void USART0_send_string(const char *ptr){
    while(*ptr !=0x00){
        USART0_send(*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
}

unsigned char USART0_receive(void) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));
    return UDR0;
}

void USART0_read_string(char *array, uint8_t bufsize){
    uint8_t i = 0;
    char c;
    
    // Receive characters until newline or buffer limit
    while (i < bufsize - 1) {
        c = USART0_receive();
        if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            break;
        }
        array[i++] = c;
    }

    array[i] = '\0';
}

EDIT 1: OK, I've updated the build log again.
------ Build started: Project: TEST_ATMEL, Configuration: Debug AVR ------
Build started.
Project "TEST_ATMEL.cproj" (default targets):
Target "PreBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PreBuildEvent)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Compiler.targets" from project "C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL.cproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
    Task "RunCompilerTask"
        Shell Utils Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\shellUtils\make.exe all --jobs 12 --output-sync 
        Building file: .././motor.c
        Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\include"  -Og -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "motor.d" -MT"motor.d" -MT"motor.o"   -o "motor.o" ".././motor.c" 
        Finished building: .././motor.c
        Building file: .././main.c
        Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0
        .././main.c: In function 'uart_print_num':
C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\main.c(20,2): warning: implicit declaration of function 'snprintf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%ld", num);
          ^
C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\main.c(20,2): warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'snprintf'
C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\main.c(20,2): info: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'snprintf'
        .././main.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\main.c(37,7): warning: unused variable 'ptr' [-Wunused-variable]
          char ptr[100]="he\n";
               ^
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\include"  -Og -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "main.d" -MT"main.d" -MT"main.o"   -o "main.o" ".././main.c" 
        Finished building: .././main.c
        Building file: .././sensor.c
        Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\include"  -Og -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "sensor.d" -MT"sensor.d" -MT"sensor.o"   -o "sensor.o" ".././sensor.c" 
        Finished building: .././sensor.c
        Building file: .././uart.c
        Invoking: AVR/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"  -x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\include"  -Og -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mrelax -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "uart.d" -MT"uart.d" -MT"uart.o"   -o "uart.o" ".././uart.c" 
        Finished building: .././uart.c
        Building target: TEST_ATMEL.elf
        Invoking: AVR/GNU Linker : 5.4.0
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe" -o TEST_ATMEL.elf  main.o motor.o sensor.o uart.o   -Wl,-Map="TEST_ATMEL.map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mrelax -mmcu=atmega2560 -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.7.374\gcc\dev\atmega2560"  
        Finished building target: TEST_ATMEL.elf
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature -R .user_signatures  "TEST_ATMEL.elf" "TEST_ATMEL.hex"
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -j .eeprom  --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  --no-change-warnings -O ihex "TEST_ATMEL.elf" "TEST_ATMEL.eep" || exit 0
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objdump.exe" -h -S "TEST_ATMEL.elf" > "TEST_ATMEL.lss"
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-objcopy.exe" -O srec -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature -R .user_signatures "TEST_ATMEL.elf" "TEST_ATMEL.srec"
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-size.exe" "TEST_ATMEL.elf"
           text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
            586      18       0     604     25c TEST_ATMEL.elf
    Done executing task "RunCompilerTask".
    Task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask"
                Program Memory Usage    :   604 bytes   0,2 % Full
                Data Memory Usage       :   18 bytes   0,2 % Full
                Warning: Memory Usage estimation may not be accurate if there are sections other than .text sections in ELF file
    Done executing task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask".
Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "TEST_ATMEL.cproj".
Target "PostBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PostBuildEvent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Target "Build" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Avr.common.targets" from project "C:\Users\H.Dani\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL\TEST_ATMEL.cproj" (entry point):
Done building target "Build" in project "TEST_ATMEL.cproj".
Done building project "TEST_ATMEL.cproj".

Build succeeded.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

EDIT 2: I've added below the schematics of the MCU and FT232 with the USB connector and how these are tied together. I'd say they are pretty self explanatory, the FT232 is tied to the RX and TX of the MCU (originally I messed up the schematic and even printed the board with the RX and TX wired wrongly, but luckly I fixed that part).


EDIT 4: Forgot to mention that I use an USBasp programmer to flash the hex to my board via AVRDUDESS which is configured as the image shows below. Don't know if this is relevant.


sounds like you've set up the serial port on the host computer and your AVR differently. Check that you've got the same number of stop bits, frame length and so on. (honestly, this is the reason why USB was a relatively quick success: Try to explain to a computer user today that they need to match the configuration of their COM: port to that of the mouse they try to use)

@MarcusMüller, I used the Arduino IDE serial monitor a couple of times, but I'm not sure if it is configured for 8 data bits and 1 stop bit communication. However, I've used Putty also, and it is configured for 9600 baud, 8 data bits and 1 stop bit with no parity.

So if your example works, why not give an example that does not work? Does the LED on PORTF work as expected?

@Justme, the commented code which is above the USART0_read_string call in main works, but when I try reading strings and comparing them with strcmp the led doesn't light up which leads me to think that something is lost along the track. However, when I print these characters with USART0_send_string(read) they are printed just fine on the terminal. Even more strangely though, when I try to print USART0_send_string("RECEIVED\n") I get garbage on the terminal.

You might want to also explain the environment better. There is no "AVR-C" for example. Which compiler you are using, and how do you link the output file, what startup library you are using etc? The thing is string literals may reside in flash instead of SRAM so you can't use strcmp with literals or the char array ptr is not correctly initialized by startup code with the string literal data.

Would you mind to [edit] your question and add the command lines to build the program, please? We would like to reproduce your observation.

@thebusybee done, I've added the command line build output.

@Justme, I use Microchip Studio 7. I basically compile and build the files into the .hex, and then use AVRDUDESS with the Atmega2560 presets to flash the hex file onto the board. The fuses are: L - 0xFF, H - 0xD8, E - 0xFD, LB - 0x3F.

@hdaniu can you post the schematics of your board, especially the part how you connect the AVR to PC, and describe how you connected it? Also the full code is unknown, we cannot know if baud rate settings etc are correct.

@emacsdrivesmenuts The provided source clearly shows that USART0_read_string terminates the input by CR or LF and appends a '\0'. The size argument just limits the number of stored characters.

Thank you for the perfectly copied build log. Would you mind to "clear" the build and repeat the build? As the log shows, there was no need to build the program, and so we cannot see the actual commands to compile and link.

You might need to delete object files and executable manually to clear (I don't use that IDE and don't know about options). Additionally you might want to investigate that build log for yourself and try to understand it. Such knowledge is most valuable for your progress in software development.

@thebusybee I've added the command lines for the build again. I hope I understood correctly what you were asking for. I also added some stuff to the code besides the UART.

@Justme, I've added the schematics

The issue seams to be bound to the use of const string literals like "ST", "SO" or "RECEIVED\n". This may be a problem with the compiler settings. This MCU cannot directly access data stored in flash memory, special instructions (LPM / ELPM) are required to read from there, they are different from RAM access.
So your USART0_send_string() can send data stored in RAM (the received data), but not the string "RECEIVED\n" because this is stored in flash memory and the address of the string, interpreted as RAM address, points to other bytes, the received garbage.
These literals must be copied to RAM before they can be accessed as data. So the compiler must either generate code to copy these strings before your code starts or you need special code to read data from flash.
Reading a byte from flash in an AVR context needs a call to "pgm_read_byte()", however the MEGA2560 has more than 64 kB flash and in this case you probably need to call "pgm_read_byte_far()".
I don't know exactly how this is solved in Atmel Studio 7, but I recommend to try these suggestions:

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const char s_Received[] PROGMEM = "RECEIVED\n";
// there exists a newer alternative syntax like this:
// const __flash char s_Received[] = "RECEIVED\n";

void USART0_send_flash_string(PGM_P ptr) {
    char c;
    while((c = pgm_read_byte_far(ptr)) != 0x00) {
        USART0_send(c);
        ptr++;
    }
}

The header file "pgmspace.h" offers some additional string functions. You may want to use "strcmp_P()" or "strcmp_PF()", where the 2nd parameter is a string in flash, in your receiver parser.

Just tried this out @Jens, but it seems to get stuck in the while loop of the USART0_send_flash_string function forever and still ends up printing nonsense. I'll experiment some more tho with this. I've also tried my previous code with an off-the-shelf Arduino Mega 2560 and the behavior is exactly the same, so I think it might indeed be related to the MCU being unable to read from flash.

pgm_read_far_address needs an uint_farptr_t which PGM_P isn't. Use pgm_get_far_address for example. And PGM_P is deprecated.

Are there any settings that I could change in Microchip Studio so that when my code compiles it places any of the strings that would end up in flash memory in RAM firstly?

I tested your code using Atmel Studio 7 on one of my controller boards containing an atMega2560. There was no problem at 38400,8N1 and 115200,8N1. The strings "SO" and "ST" are recognized, the output follows and "RECEIVED\n" was sent and received in a terminal. My alternative code using strings from flash also works. I had a look at the produced assembly code. The compiler copies all string literals, that are not tagged with PROGMEM to RAM locations before calling main(). If you provide the *.lss file, I might find a difference to my compiler output.
